# Delete post with smallest id SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
Delete from post 
where id_post 
in 
( 
    select MIN(id_post)
    from post
    where id_owner='2'
)
```

Returns:
"You can't specify target table 'post' for update in FROM clause"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL, if you're doing an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE on a table, you can't reference that table in an inner query (you can however reference a field from that outer table...)

The solution is to replace the instance of post in the sub-query with (select MIN(id_post)
    from post
    where id_owner='2' ), like this

```
Delete from post 
where id_post 
in 
( 
    select id_post 
    from (select MIN(id_post)
    from post
    where id_owner='2') as A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

```
Delete p
    from post p
    where id_owner = 2
    order by id_post
    limit 1;
```

Note:  Don't use single quotes around numeric constants.  I am guessing `id_owner` is numeric.